# Prevent the same user to log in more than once laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, authentication

I just want to prevent the same user to login more than once from different browsers until the session timeout or the user logout... any ideas ?!

Comment: I think you can only manage that by storing login status in the database like upon login, set login column to true and upon logout set login status to false.

And upon login, first, check that login column is false or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only manage that by storing login status in the database like upon login, set login column to true and upon logout set login status to false. And upon login, first, check that login column is false or not.

BTW can you please tell us that why do you want to do that, so that we can suggest some other way out?

Comment: It's a request from the client to prevent more than one login, I already has a login log to save the login and logout and failure login attempts. I need to fire and Event when the session timeout put using laravel not javascript , because the JS one not work correctly.
Any ideas about firing the Event when the session timeout ?